# javascript select all data-attributes

Tags: javascript, css, html

How can select all data-attributes and return an array

```
<ul data-cars="ford">
 <li data-model="mustang"></li>
 <li data-color="blue"></li>
 <li data-doors="5"></li>
</ul>
```

Array should return model, color and doors.

Comment: You can use `element.attributes` to get all attributes of a node and then filter them based on your criteria.

Comment: A) Stack Overflow isn't a code-my-solution-for-me site. B) If you want people to do something like this, then you need to specify *exactly* what you are wanting. It's not clear if you want *all* data attributes, or just those which are on `<li>` elements, or if you're going to have a bunch of these and want it as an Array of Arrays by  `data-cars`, or as an Object with keys of `data-cars` (although that looks like it's going to have collisions, as `data-cars` is really "make", which is not unique), or if there's only going to be only one of these structures on the page, etc.

Comment: Also, it's not clear if people should be getting "all data-attributes and return an array", or just "return model, color and doors". In other words, a general solution for *all* data-attributes, or just the specific ones in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-[name]` attribute on elements can be accessed directly via the DOM using `element.dataset`

```js
var allData = [];
//var matches = document.querySelectorAll("li,ul"); < will return ul and il data attributes
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  allData.push(matches[i].dataset)
}
console.log(allData);
```

```html
<ul data-cars="ford">
  <li data-model="mustang"></li>
  <li data-color="blue"></li>
  <li data-doors="5"></li>
</ul>
```

You can use also JQuery as below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var allData = [];

  $('li').each(function() {
    allData.push($(this).data());
    console.log(allData);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-cars="ford">
  <li data-model="mustang"></li>
  <li data-color="blue"></li>
  <li data-doors="5"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get attributes from any dom element using the **getAttribute** method. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

The following code will get you what you need as an array

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li')).map((el) => el.getAttribute('data-model') || el.getAttribute('data-color') || el.getAttribute('data-doors'))
```

Comment: If you're going to limit compatibility by using `Array.from()`, why not use [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)? Admittedly, both of the newer methodologies tend to be slower.